# Prevent Ctrl+S in Yakuake

Tags: vim, shell, kde

How do I prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> from suspending output in Yakuake?

I need it to give it to the opened program in the console (such as Vim, I want to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save in Vim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your .bashrc or .zshrc

```
stty ixany
stty ixoff -ixon
```

Comment: wow, when i press ctrl+s, it shows `(i-search)'':` something that i don't know what the use for.. (i know that ctrl+r do a reverse search, but this one does nothing)

Comment: @Kokizzu Try to press `ctrl-p` for at least one time and press `ctrl-s`. You will be able to search the history commands you've scrolled through using `ctrl-p`

Answer (score 1):

nevermind, found it :3

just add these on bashrc

```
vim() {
  local STTYOPTS="$(stty --save)"
  stty stop '' -ixoff
  command vim "$@"
  stty "$STTYOPTS"
}
```

reference:  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files